# Reading integers from a file and rewriting them in a new one

Tags: java

I'm trying to pull integers from a file and write them into some cases to save me from having to copy and paste so much. Here is what I have:

```
public class PullFrom {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("PullFrom.txt"));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("OutPutFile.txt", true));
        int ID;

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            ID = input.nextInt();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                try {
                    out.write("case " + ID + ":");
                    out.newLine();
                    out.write("setRandomWalk(false);");
                    out.newLine();
                    out.write("break;");
                    out.newLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Cannot Do It");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        out.close();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

In Eclipse I am getting this in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at reader.PullFrom.main(PullFrom.java:17)
```

This error repeats itself in the console several times. Along with my "Cannot Do It" Text.

This is an example of my "PullFrom.txt" file:

```
524
1988
7823
6723
```

And finally, what the program generates in my output file:

```
case 524:
setRandomWalk(false);
break;
```

Which appears to be correct, but it only prints out the first int..

Comment: In your for loop you have i < 1 so of course its only going to do one line. I'd just remove the for loop.

Comment: The for loop is inside the while loop, if I change thefor loop to loop 10 times, it will loop the same integer over and over rather than grabbing a new one on the next line.

Comment: If you have so many cases that have the same operation, in languages such as C,C++,Java etc., you can just put all the case labels together - no point in writing the `setRandomWalk(false);break;` more than once. And you don't need to write a program to achieve this - usually the IDE's search-and-replace will do fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `out.close()` on each iteration of your loop.  Put the call to `out.close()` outside your while loop block.

Edit: After your change, you should try checking `hasNextLine()` and also `hasNextInt()` in your while loop expression.  If that still produces an exception, you could wrap your call in a try/catch, and exit the loop if the catch is triggered.

```
while(input.hasNextLine() && input.hasNextInt()) {
  try {
     ...
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Noticed that just before I refreshed my page, I changed it, now I'm getting a                 

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at reader.PullFrom.main(PullFrom.java:17)

Comment: Done. Updated Code in the Question as well as new error.

Comment: Thank you, checking for both a next line and a next int solved my problem and there were no exceptions thrown.

Comment: Great , glad it solved your problem :) If you could please mark this answer as correct, I would be very thankful.